# How to retrieve a list of values from a list of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, orm, sequelize.js

So I have a list of objects like this formed by Sequelize query:

```
  [
  Likes {
    dataValues: { PlaceId: 'e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd' },
    _previousDataValues: { PlaceId: 'e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd' },
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  Likes {
    dataValues: { PlaceId: '417f55a6-1d64-491f-9c00-8f3094f3f53a' },
    _previousDataValues: { PlaceId: '417f55a6-1d64-491f-9c00-8f3094f3f53a' },
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
```

I am getting various exceptions when querying because I get either a list like that:  [{PlaceId: 'e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd'}, {PlaceId: 'e678yt6-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d67326au'}] or an empty list: [].

I tried out Object.values as well as valueOf, map and other built in methods - even a manual for cycle and I do not really get why don't they work. What methods of achieving that can you suggest?

Solution:

```
return  models.Likes.findAll({
            where: {
                UserId: req.user.id
            },
            attributes: ['PlaceId']
        }).then(likes => {
            var values;
            try {
                values = likes.map(entity => entity.get('PlaceId'))
            }
            catch (e){
                console.log(e);
            }
            models.Place.findAll({
                where: {
                    id: {
                        [Sequelize.Op.notIn]: values
                    }
                },
                limit: 24
            })
```

This is the final working solution written thanks to one of the suggestions. Mapping with (entity => entity.get) did the trick. Best regards to everybody who commented and helped.

If anybody needs, the thing does a sequelize query from one table to then query another table with a "NOT IN". In SQL query 2ould look like that:

```
"SELECT "id", "coordinates", "place_name", "description", "category", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Places" AS "Place" WHERE "Place"."id" NOT IN ('e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd', '417f55a6-1d64-491f-9c00-8f3094f3f53a') LIMIT 24;"
```

Comment: The right approach is using `map` can you please show what you tried there?

Comment: This is not a valid `Array` (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{')

Comment: In your example you have an object `dataValues: { PlaceId: 'e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd' }` and not an array

Comment: @mplungjan it is an array of objects (console logged and copies, just put one object in the example, so that it would not be overloaded). Added a list of two to clearify

Comment: @KooiInc console logged and coppied fully - should be valid

Comment: @MonikaGornostajūtė Sorry, Your examples do not match your description. `[{"placeid":"xxx"},{"placeid":"zzz"}]` is an array of objects. This:  `Likes {
    dataValues: { PlaceId: 'e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd' },
    _previousDataValues: { PlaceId: 'e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd' },` is not

Comment: @mplungjan sorry for misleading, I make an assumption that if several things are in [ ] braces (like it is in an example) - it is an array. I know that Likes {     dataValues: { PlaceId: 'e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd' },     _previousDataValues: { PlaceId: 'e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd' } itself is not an array, but several of those together - is, as I thought.

Comment: `I get either a list like that: [{PlaceId: 'e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd'}, {PlaceId: 'e678yt6-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d67326au'}] or an empty list: [].` so I expected `dataValues: [ here is an array ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, it should be sufficiant for you

```js
const FirstTable = sequelize.model(`FirstTable`)
const list = await FirstTable.findAll({
    attributes: [`PlaceId`]
})
    .then(data => {
        return data.map(entity => entity.get('PlaceId'))
    })
console.log(list)
```

The output will be:

```js
[
  'e61d2360-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d38276dd',
  'e678yt6-c846-46b5-aa25-6534d67326au'
]
```

Comment: thank you so much!, applied this to the code and it worked, apparently, mapping without => expression was my mistake